# Hidden property in django widget field

Tags: django, widget

I have this widget field:

```
{% include "partials/field.html" with field=form_request.state|attr:"value:open"|attr:"readonly:true" %}
```

Need to hide it, anyone knows the attr needed for it ?, already tried :

```
{% include "partials/field.html" with field=form_request.state|attr:"value:Abierto"|attr:"readonly:true"|attr:"Hidden:true" %}
```

But it doesn't work
Thanx

Comment: `|attr:"hidden"` does not work, or `|attr:"type:hidden"`?

Comment: As I already told you, this logic belongs in the form definition itself, not in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a hidden input form field you should use the `type` attribute with the value `hidden` - `"type:hidden"`:

```
{% include "partials/field.html" with field=form_request.state|attr:"value:Abierto"|attr:"readonly:true"|attr:"type:hidden" %}
```

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```
{% include "partials/field.html" with field=form_request.state|attr:"value:Abierto"|attr:"readonly:true"|attr:"class:hidden" %}
```

and in css:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, found it !